# Load Array in UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I want to make paging swipe left and right using `UIScrollView` after view `detailController`.

First, `main.m`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    OZDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[OZDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OZDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.arrDetailNews = [_arrNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    OZDetailViewController *arrNewsAll = [[OZDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OZDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    arrNewsAll.allNewsArray = _arrNews;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:arrNewsAll animated:YES];
}
```

When I selected content in `tableviewcell`, `arrDetailNews` can loaded in method `viewDidLoad()` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`. But `arrNewsAll` cannot loaded in method `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`.

This is my `detailViewController.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *allNewsArray;
```

And `detailViewCOntroller.m`:

```
@synthesize allNewsArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    NSLog(@"dataArray: %@", allNewsArray);
}

- (int)numberINSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"dataArrayCell: %@", allNewsArray);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"New Cell"];
    }

    if(indexPath.row != self.arrDetailNews.count-1){
        UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 2)];
        line.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell addSubview:line];
    }

    tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"1st";
    }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"2nd";
    }
    if (indexPath.row==2) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"3rd";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

If `allNewsArray` can loaded in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` I can continue next step for paging with `UIScrollView`. Note, `numberOfRowsInSection` I set to `4` because I need `4` rows (custom view).

Comment: Can you check if you connected correctly the delegate and the datasource to the view controller?

Comment: hi luca Bartoletti. yes i was connected my tableView to delegate and datasource. but i have two array in didSelectRowAtIndexPath 1st for selected array 2nd for all array. for the 1st array that is not issue i can parse the array. but in the 2nd array i cannot NSLog in method cellForRowAtIndexPath. any idea? my goal is i wan to paging content with UIScroolView

Comment: Can you try to rewrite the question?

Comment: hi luca i was rewrite my question. maybe you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you setup your delegate & dataSource outlets correctly from xib/storyboard, you still need to specify the number of rows per section (or number of sections).

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return allNewsArray.count;
}
```

Alternatively, the method for number of sections is:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

Comment: hi jakaenberg. yes i was connected my tableView to delegate and datasource in my xib. but i have two array in didSelectRowAtIndexPath 1st for selected array 2nd for all array. for the 1st array that is not issue i can parse the array. but in the 2nd array i cannot NSLog in method cellForRowAtIndexPath. any idea? my goal is i wan to paging content with UIScroolView